# Is Result of Lossless compression is really the original data?

Tags: video, compression

I would like to know ,Is result of Lossless compression on data produces bit for bit perfect match with original data ,if so then what use of having such compression.Is it really useful to use Lossless compression??

Comment: Is this a trick question? Of course, the result of lossless compression ist NOT the original data. It is a compressed version of the data. ;-)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression.It says that result of lossless compression is original data

Comment: @Amit: no, it says `This means that when the data is decompressed, the result is a bit-for-bit perfect match with the original.` Henrik is being funny: obviously the "Result" of lossless compression is a compressed version of the original.  I think what you really mean is "the result of compression, transmission, and decompression" is the original data.

Comment: I am looking for data after decompression ,is it equal to original data.If So then how this technique is useful??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, lossless means just that.

For example, ZIP compression of files is *expected* to restore the original file -- and it does.

And of course, we know that files are ZIPPED to reduce their size in full confidence of being able to restore the original.

Comment: To be more precise ,i wanted to talk about lossless compression on a image file.

Comment: Many image file formats are compressed anyway, so further LOSSLESS compression won't have much effect on size.

Comment: Only benefit i see using Lossless compression is it increase Transmission efficiency.Is There any other use of having Lossless compression??

Comment: If you're referring to the compression of files for transmission through networks, then yes, there's a benefit. For example, I compress a lot of files with *gzip* so they are smaller and backups require less space and take less time. But if you only have to worry about image files like JPEG, they're already compressed and I wouldn't bother compressing them with lossless compression.

Comment: Thanks for your response @pavium ,What you alluding is gzip is based on Lossless compression ,is it right??

Comment: Yes, GZIP, ZIP, BZIP2, 7zip and others are lossless. Lossy compression is only found built in to image formats.

Answer (score 0):

Some forms of data *must* be reproduced bit-for-bit upon extraction, notably executable code and memory contents. Lossless compression allows it to be stored and/or transmitted in less space while still being usable.